# How to return set of statement on accepting the request from the client machine in php?

Tags: php, linux

I have been assigned write a php code to return a set of linux commands soon after the 'clients' connects to the 'server'.
I have tried using `&_SERVER` tags to extract the client info

Comment: This question is to broad and also unclear as to what you are asking. Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: what am trying to ask is, i need to generate a kickstart install commands for centOS dynamically when a system tries to connect with the server. and one of the commands in the kickstart config is 'root password' is an hash  version of the clients's mac address. hope am clear now .